# Updating and deleting items in List, SwiftUI

Tags: listview, swiftui, swiftui-list

In to-do style list, I have 2 issues with updating the List.

1. When deleting item in the List, it flies away to random places. (glitchy). I guess that it's something about having it right with unique `identifier`
2. When ticking off item in the List, it doesn't change the section. The View updates only after new item is added.

- Additionally, maybe you know how to hide section, when there're no more items there, and reappear if tasks added.

[image]
[image]

**ListView**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var listViewModel = ListViewModel()
    
    @State var newItem = ""
        
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Form {
                // To-do section
                Section(header: Text("New")) {
                    ForEach(listViewModel.itemCellViewModels) { itemCellViewModel in
                        
                        if itemCellViewModel.item.accomplished == false {
                            
                            ItemCellView(itemCellViewModel: itemCellViewModel)
                        }
                        
                    }.onDelete(perform: { indexSet in
                        //remove item from the shopping list
                        self.listViewModel.itemCellViewModels.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
                        print(indexSet)
                    })
                    .onDelete(perform: listViewModel.removeRows)
                }
                
                // Accomplished section
                Section(header: Text("Done")) {
                    ForEach(listViewModel.itemCellViewModels.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                        if listViewModel.itemCellViewModels[index].item.accomplished == true {
                            ItemCellView(itemCellViewModel: listViewModel.itemCellViewModels[index])
                        }
                    }.onDelete(perform: listViewModel.removeRows)
                    
                }
            }
            
            
            
            TextField("Enter item here", text: $newItem) { _ in
                
            } onCommit: {
                self.listViewModel.addItem(item: Item(productName: newItem, accomplished: false))
                newItem = ""
            }
            .autocapitalization(.none)
            .padding()
            .border(Color.blue)
            .padding()
        }
        // update ViewModel with placeholder data
        .onAppear(perform: {self.listViewModel.itemCellViewModels.append(contentsOf: placeholderItems)})
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

var placeholderItems = [
    ItemViewModel(item: Item(productName: "1", accomplished: false)),
    ItemViewModel(item: Item(productName: "2", accomplished: false)),
    ItemViewModel(item: Item(productName: "3", accomplished: false)),
    ItemViewModel(item: Item(productName: "4", accomplished: false)),
    ItemViewModel(item: Item(productName: "5", accomplished: false)),
    ItemViewModel(item: Item(productName: "6", accomplished: true)),
    ItemViewModel(item: Item(productName: "7", accomplished: true)),
    ItemViewModel(item: Item(productName: "8", accomplished: true)),
    ItemViewModel(item: Item(productName: "9", accomplished: true)),
    ItemViewModel(item: Item(productName: "10", accomplished: true))
]

/// The rest of the code

// Reusable View for Cells
struct ItemCellView: View {
    @ObservedObject var itemCellViewModel: ItemViewModel
    
    // send an item (doesn't return anything)
    var onCommit: (Item) -> (Void) = { _ in }
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(itemCellViewModel.item.productName)
            }
            Spacer()
            
            Button(action: {
                
                itemCellViewModel.item.accomplished.toggle()
                
            }, label: {
                Image(systemName: (itemCellViewModel.item.accomplished ? "checkmark.square" : "square"))
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
            })
        }.opacity(itemCellViewModel.item.accomplished ? 0.3 : 1)
    }
}

import Foundation
import Combine

class ItemViewModel: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    
    @Published var item: Item
    
    var id = UUID()
    @Published var items: [Item] = []
    @Published var completionStateIconName = ""
    
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    init(item: Item) {
        self.item = item
        
        $item
            .map { item in
                item.accomplished ? "checkmark.square" : "square"
            }
            .assign(to: \.completionStateIconName, on: self)
            .store(in: &cancellables) // <- for memory management purposes
        
    }
}

class ListViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var itemCellViewModels = [ItemViewModel]()
    
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    func addItem(item: Item) {
        let itemVM = ItemViewModel(item: item)
        self.itemCellViewModels.append(itemVM)
    }
    
    func removeRows(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        itemCellViewModels.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
    }
}

// Model
struct Item: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var productName: String
    var accomplished: Bool
}
```

**Reusable View For Cells**

```
struct ItemCellView: View {
    @ObservedObject var itemCellViewModel: ItemViewModel
    
    // send an item (doesn't return anything)
    var onCommit: (Item) -> (Void) = { _ in }
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(itemCellViewModel.item.productName)
            }
            Spacer()
            
            Button(action: {
                
                itemCellViewModel.item.accomplished.toggle()
                
            }, label: {
                Image(systemName: (itemCellViewModel.item.accomplished ? "checkmark.square" : "square"))
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
            })
        }.opacity(itemCellViewModel.item.accomplished ? 0.3 : 1)
    }
}
```

**ItemViewModel**

```
import Foundation
import Combine

class ItemViewModel: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    
    @Published var item: Item
    
    var id = UUID()
    @Published var items: [Item] = []
    @Published var completionStateIconName = ""
    
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    init(item: Item) {
        self.item = item
        
        $item
            .map { item in
                item.accomplished ? "checkmark.square" : "square"
            }
            .assign(to: \.completionStateIconName, on: self)
            .store(in: &cancellables) // <- for memory management purposes
        
    }
}
```

**ListViewModel**

```
import Foundation
import Combine

class ListViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var itemCellViewModels = [ItemViewModel]()
    
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    func addItem(item: Item) {
        let itemVM = ItemViewModel(item: item)
        self.itemCellViewModels.append(itemVM)
    }
    
    func removeRows(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        itemCellViewModels.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
struct Item: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var productName: String
    var accomplished: Bool
}
```

Comment: what would you change `productName` to for better readability ? mb `Item.` ... `value` / `name` / `description`?

Comment: I'd suggest `name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have added the wrong `ForEach`.
As you need to add only those object which is accomplished or not. You need to use a filter instead of iterate all the objects and check the condition inside the ForEach. By removing this your first issues solve animation and you can also add an empty condition so when your accomplished array is empty the section automatically removes it from the view.

As the bellow demo, we used different arrays for both sections so the index of the section row will change and your source of data is a single array. For this, you need to remove the item from the array by id.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var listViewModel = ListViewModel()
    
    var arrNotAccomplished: [ItemViewModel] {
        return listViewModel.itemCellViewModels.filter({!$0.item.accomplished})
    }
    var arrAccomplished: [ItemViewModel] {
        return listViewModel.itemCellViewModels.filter({$0.item.accomplished})
    }
    
    @State var newItem = ""
        
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Form {
                   // To-do section
                if !arrNotAccomplished.isEmpty {
                    Section(header: Text("New")) {
                        ForEach(arrNotAccomplished) { itemCellViewModel in
                            ItemCellView(itemCellViewModel: itemCellViewModel) { (_) -> (Void) in
                                self.listViewModel.objectWillChange.send()
                            }
                        }.onDelete { (index) in
                            guard let firstIndex = index.first else { return }
                            self.listViewModel.removeRows(for: arrNotAccomplished[firstIndex].id)
                        }
                    }
                }
                   // Accomplished section
                   if !arrAccomplished.isEmpty {
                       Section(header: Text("Done")) {
                           ForEach(arrAccomplished) { itemCellViewModel in
                               ItemCellView(itemCellViewModel: itemCellViewModel) { (_) -> (Void) in
                                   self.listViewModel.objectWillChange.send()
                               }
                           }.onDelete { (index) in
                            guard let firstIndex = index.first else { return }
                            self.listViewModel.removeRows(for: arrAccomplished[firstIndex].id)
                        }
                       }
                   }
               }
            
//            ====== other body view code =========
```

Updated remove function code.

```
func removeRows(for id: UUID) {
        self.itemCellViewModels.removeAll(where: {$0.id == id})
}
```

---

Issue 2:
Some time nested array will not affect when update data inside the inner array.

I used your `onCommit()` closure and send action to main parent view and update view forcefully.

```
struct ItemCellView: View {
    @ObservedObject var itemCellViewModel: ItemViewModel
    
    // send an item (doesn't return anything)
    var onCommit: (Item) -> (Void) = { _ in }
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(itemCellViewModel.item.productName)
            }
            Spacer()
            
            Button(action: {
                itemCellViewModel.item.accomplished.toggle()
                onCommit(itemCellViewModel.item) //<-- Here
            }, label: {
                Image(systemName: (itemCellViewModel.item.accomplished ? "checkmark.square" : "square"))
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
            })
        }.opacity(itemCellViewModel.item.accomplished ? 0.3 : 1)
    }
}
```

Note: No need for two `.onDelete` for the first section.

---

**Note:**
If you still facing glitchy animation then use main queue.

```
.onDelete(perform: { (indexSet) in
   DispatchQueue.main.async {
      listViewModel.removeRows(at: indexSet)
   }
})
```

Even in your code delete the item from the array with some delay it will work.

Comment: Thank you! added
```withAnimation { onCommit(itemCellViewModel.item) } ```

Comment: Removing cells still remains a problem, for ex., try deleting row 7, it deletes other elements instead.

Comment: @MikeMaus I miss this point. Please check the updated answere.

Comment: it works amazing! I previously tried the following `ForEach(arrNotAccomplished, id: \.self.item.id)` thinking that it should remove by the id mentioned in key path. This didn't work out.